# Tailwind producing weirdly different results on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, svelte

I have been creating a website using SvelteKit and TailwindCSS and mainly using Google Chrome. I opened the website in Firefox for a change and it produced wildly different results!
The top bar on Chrome looks like this and is my preferred look:[image]

While the top bar on Firefox looks like this: [image]

The header component looks like this in code

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-1 sm:grid-rows-1 gap-y-2 mt-2 sm:mt-4 sm:pl-4 align-middle h-24 md:h-16">
    <div class="lg:col-start-2 col-span-7 md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3 flex flex-row">
        <div class="h-full">
            <img
                class="hidden sm:block h-full my-auto"
                src="https://dutchellie.nl/DutchEllie/proper-website-2/raw/branch/main/web/static/images/icon.png"
                alt="Icon"
            />
            <div class="block sm:hidden ml-2 mt-4">
                <Hamburger />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full sm:w-auto sm:pl-5 sm:my-auto text-center mx-auto sm:mx-0 pr-9 sm:pr-0">
            <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-3xl h-min font-medium">Internetica Galactica 2</h1>
            <p class="h-min text-xs">Surviving the rewriting</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden md:col-start-5 col-start-1 col-end-7 sm:grid grid-cols-6">
        <nav class="h-full flex items-end md:col-start-4 md:col-span-2 col-span-7 gap-2 text-md">
            <Button link="/" text="Home" />
            <Button link="/about" text="About" />
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-->
    <hr class="col-span-full border-slate-700" />
</!-->
</div>
```

What could be the difference here? I have absolutely no idea!
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you checked that neither of your browsers have saved a certain zoom-level? (`Ctrl + 0` or `Cmd + 0` should reset the scaling in either browser)

Comment: Have not checked that, but neither are zoomed. See my own answered question below for the answer. Not entirely satisfied with the solution, but it works well enough

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after a bit of back and forth, have a workaround solution.
First, the problem appears to be a misbehaving width on the image next to the title in the header, which pushes the header text over to the right.
The solution finally comes from the fact that the logo is square, so I could set the aspect-square property to force it's width to match it's height.

Now the logo isn't pushing the title to the right and the two behave

Comment: Was about to answer with the same observation. Though, do you mean `aspect-ratio: 1`? Have not heard of `aspect-square` and did not find it in the Tailwind classes either.

Comment: [Tailwind: Aspect Ratio](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio)